# Win API absolute beginnings - where to start?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have no idea what Win API is, but I have to learn in quite quickly - could you please provide me with some good learning resources for that?
I have googled quite a lot so far - but I mainly read chunks of information - nothing consistent and for absolute beginners.
Thank you!

Comment: Charles Petzold, Programming Windows

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/329776/a-good-book-to-understand-winapi-programming. Also, make sure you know enough C++ before beginning to try to understand things. It goes a lot easier if you know the pre-WINAPI before actually starting.

Comment: This is 50% exact duplicate, and 50% way-too-fuzzy a question for here.  Anyways, learn about plain old ANSI C (not C++), get Petzold.

Comment: "Win API" is somewhat large and in purest form is not necessary easiest for "absolute beginners". Clarifying what your actual needs are will help to answer (also likely not on this site - maybe programers one).

Comment: Of course every so often I find myself thinking "Maybe I'll try to do something new, let's make a trackbar!". Easy to follow when you have a goal in mind. IMO the whole winapi can be thought of as little projects like that.

Comment: This type of question is a very poor fit for StackOverflow's design of questions with specific (acceptable) single answers, and is specifically mentioned as not being appropriate in the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) because it asks for opinion, speculation, and discussion.

Answer (score 2):

I started with this one and helped me a lot:

[Welcome to theForger's Win32 API Tutorial](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/)

Read a bit on [Windows Programming](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Programming) as well.

Comment: I started with that one too ^_^ Found it pretty good.

Comment: :D.. its for babies like us... loved it ..

Answer (score 1):

The classic book about the Windows API is Petzold's [Programming Windows](http://www.charlespetzold.com/pw5/).